# <f:convertNumber />and <f:convertDateTime /> is not working inside primefaces dialog

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am working with jsf 2.1 and primefaces 3.5

I am using "f:convertNumber"  and "f:convertDateTime" to format the numbers and date, it is working in normal screen but, it is not working in dialog box(Once add button pressed, i am displaying the dialog box).

Here is my code:

```
<p:dialog id="receiptdialogprint" modal="true" widgetVar="printDlgId" header="Success" draggable="true" closable="false" resizable="false" maximizable="false" minimizable="false" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:11px;" appendToBody="true" width="50%">
    <h:form id="receiptdialog_form">
        <p:panelGrid id="payment_receipt_Panel" style="width:80%">
            <p:row>
                <p:column style="text-align:left;width:45%">
                    <p:outputLabel value="Date " style="font-size:16px" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column style="text-align:left;width:45%">
                    <h:outputText id="payment_date" value=":&#160;&#160; #{paymentreceipt.paymentdate}">
                        <!--                                <f:convertDateTime for="payment_date" type="date"/> -->
                            <f:convertDateTime dateStyle="medium"/>
                        <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" />
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
            <p:row>
                <p:column style="text-align:left;width:45%">
                    <p:outputLabel value="Annual Memebership Fee(In Rs) " style="font-size:16px" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column style="text-align:left;width:45%">
                    <h:outputText value=":&#160;&#160; #{paymentreceipt.paymentannualmemberfee_without_servicetax}" >
                        <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2"/>
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
        </<p:panelGrid>
    </<h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Output it showing like this:

Date                            : Fri Aug 01 14:21:53 IST 2014

Annual Memebership Fee(In Rs)   : 3782.48487006052

For Others(In Rs)               : 889.99644001424

Expected Out put:

Date                                :Friday, 1 August, 2014

Annual Memebership Fee(Without ST)  :3,782.48

For Others(Without ST)              :890

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
             <p:row>
                <p:column style="text-align:left;width:45%">
                    <p:outputLabel value="Date :" style="font-size:16px" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column style="text-align:left;width:45%">

                    <h:outputText id="payment_date" value="#{paymentreceipt.paymentdate}">
                        <f:convertDateTime dateStyle="full" type="date"/>
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
            <p:row>
                <p:column style="text-align:left;width:45%">
                    <p:outputLabel value="Annual Memebership Fee(In Rs) :" style="font-size:16px" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column style="text-align:left;width:45%">
                    <h:outputText value="#{paymentreceipt.paymentannualmemberfee_without_servicetax}" >
                        <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2" pattern="##,##0.00"/>
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
```

I am using richfaces if we use any special characters like space or : with the date and number format. It will not convert. So replace the colon and try. If you want the colon use seperate h:outputLabel for that.

Comment: Understand my mistake...It worked fine...Thank you...:)